# Angular 2 App Component ngOnInit called twice when using iframe

Tags: angular, iframe

I'm working on an Angular 2 application that will be delivered via an iframe on other websites. Whilst testing I've noticed that when I load the application the App Component `ngOnInit()` function is being called twice.

I'm finding this weird because when I'm testing the application 'on it's own', i.e. not though an iframe the App Component `ngOnInit()` is only called once.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787863/2312637) this could happen due errors in child components. But in my case I'm not having the problem when running the application 'normally'.

**Example Code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>My App!</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
        console.log('App Component constructor()');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('App Component ngOnInit()');
    }
}
```

**Iframe Test:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My Test Page</h1>
        <!-- iframe accessing my-app component -->
        <iframe id="test-iframe" src="/#/" width="100%" height="1300px"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

I've tested the application with only an `AppComponent` to be sure that no child components are causing any issues.

**Console Output:**

[image]

Comment: I think that this behavior is quite normal, because iframe behavior like browser and re-create document therefore your component re-init again.

Comment: Okay, but if you have a page with one iframe that's displaying the Angular App, just like the Iframe Test I shown above, shouldn't the `AppComponent` be fired once?

If I was displaying the `my-app` component in two places I'd understand it.

Comment: Did you test src with abs path like <iframe id="test-iframe" src="http://localhost:3000/#/" width="100%" height="1300px"></iframe>
 ?

Comment: In the test I have the Angular Application and the test page are on the same site, just different pages. So accessing the iframe with an absolute path or not doesn't make a difference. I just tried it just in case and it still results in the `ngOnInit()` being called twice.

Comment: I tested it on apache and publish it on a sub domain http://angular2.alisch.me/iframe.html
ngOnInit and constructor run just one time. I think it may there is problem with iis.

source:http://angular2.alisch.me/ng2.zip | =>unzip=>npm install =>npm run build:prod

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, most likely the problem is, since the `ngOnInit()` method is called after the the `@Component` finishes loading, the iframe element's loading begins right after the `ngOnInit()` life cycle finishes causing the iframe `src` value to be null.

That means since the iframe is loading its self after the `ngOnInit()` is called, any`src` value coming from the components would be foreign to it, hence `null`.

Note: **Iframe is like an outside browser injected in to DOM, so it has its own loading time.**

So I would suggest using the `constructor(){}` for this kinds of things since its always called when the class is instantiated.