# ngOnInit() is called twice and getting two API responses

Tags: angular, lifecycle, ngoninit, angular-lifecycle-hooks

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = "quogen";
  response : Response[];

  constructor (private dataService : DataService) {

  }
  ngOnInit () {
      console.log("calling init");
      return this.dataService.getQuote().subscribe(data => this.response = data);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```js
<div *ngIf="response">
  <p>{{ response['content'] }}</p>
  <p>{{ response['author'] }}</p>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The API is called twice from `ngOnInit()` as far as I know. Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you return the service call? Remove `return`. As documented in Angular, `ngOnInit` should return `void`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things, I followed what you said, and still it didn't resolve the issue which I'm facing..

Comment: You say "as far as I know", can you confirm that `console.log("calling init")` is being called twice?

Comment: I don't think that the API is called twice, but your `getQuote()` observable returns two streams. Can we see your `getQuote()` method?

Comment: @RJM Yes, console.log("calling init")  called twice

Comment: @Damian-TeodorBeleș
                                     
getQuote(){
    return this._http.get<Response[]>(this.apiUrl+"random");
  }

this is an api call which returns only one response for a call.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` in the constructor to confirm that there's only one instance being created? You might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-is-ngoninit-called-twice)

Comment: @RJM I did `console.log` in the constructor, and the constructor is called twice.

Comment: Two instances of your app component are being created then, which shouldn't be happening. You shouldn't be using `<app-root>` anywhere as it is referenced in the `index.html` and you also shouldn't have any routes assigned to it. Check those and you should be able to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @RJM..
It worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

skip and take emitted events using below function.the skip(1) operator to skip the first emission and then use take(1) to ensure that only the second emission is processed by the subscribe method.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.route.queryParams
  .pipe(skip(1), take(1)) // Skip the first emission and take the second one
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.code = params['code'];
    // You can now use this.code in your component.
  });
```

}