# Angular - Constructor and ngOninit() are called twice when reload page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I'm working on an angular project, every time I reload a page, the constructor and ngOninit() method are called twice, in this case sometimes it gets 2 API calls which will cause problems. This happens only when reloading.

I've checked the template and there is no syntax and other silence error, and I took a reference on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-is-ngoninit-called-twice), none of the answers could solve my problem. So I think it might be a routing issue? Since this happens in every component.

Besides, I'm not using component-driven architecture.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.