# Why my app component ngOnInit called twice?

Tags: angular, router, init, ngoninit

I see problem in my angular project, on some pages I didn't understand why request were made twice on page refresh. I noticed that the `init` was called twice in my components. I thought to myself that this was going to be a complicated problem given the size of the project which contains a lot of lazy loading with outlet routing. But I noticed that even the `app.component` `init` was being called twice. Which I don't understand because it's the highest element in the hierarchy?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.translationService.init('customer-en');
console.log('appInit')

if (navigator.userAgent.includes("Window")) {
   this.window = true;
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787795/why-is-ngoninit-called-twice/54791011

Comment: yes, thanks ! in my main.ts i had two platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));